# What costs and limits are there for making external web calls from a Heroku app?

Tags: heroku

For a web application deployed on Heroku (on a free dyno), is there a limit for making HTTP calls to an external web service?

The calls would be performed within the request, synchronously.

By *limit* I mean maximum number of requests, bandwidth and so on.

I hope the question in appropriate for this place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external web service might have its own rate limiting.

Other than that, you mention that "the calls would be performed within the request, synchronously".

In that case, you need to be aware of the Heroku [Request Timeout](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout). Your web dyno must not spend more than 30 seconds processing a single request, before it returns a response to the client. For decent performance, your web dyno should always respond to the client within a few hundred milliseconds, and delegate any long running jobs to a [background worker dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing).

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the external web service has high throughput and negligible latency. Thus the limits, if any, would be on Heroku's side. Do you know if there are such limits?

Comment: As I said, the number of http calls that you can make to an external service within the context of a single request and until your request responds to the client is limited by the Heroku Request Timeout. Other than that, I know of no limits imposed by Heroku.